# Using htaccess to force HTTPS doesn't work

Tags: htaccess, redirects, https, mod-rewrite

NEW EDIT 28/oct/19 →
I edited the .htaccess file as you said

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php

# HTTP to HTTPS redirect
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.bebechan.net/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I also added the lines in wp.config :

```
/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix = 'mIQnU';


define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
define('FORCE_SSL', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN',true);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */
```

I checked the wp settings and my addresses are well written (https://bebechan.net). I even downloaded a plugin to redirect every http:/bebechan.net/ebook to https://bebechan.net/ebook.

STILL NOT WORKING sadly : (. Every time I go to bebechan.net/ebook, it's not https but http.

Something I wanna point out is that, even when I go directly to the https://bebechan.net/ebook, I can access the 'buy' page, BUT, the little green lock doesn't appear, I checked the 'why no padlock' website (https://www.whynopadlock.com/results/cf25cdd8-0cde-4cfb-bfc6-1dc0ac4e2e12) and it's written that 'You currently have TLSv1 enabled'. Might this be part of the problem? Should I fix it?

---

BIG EDIT: The host that takes care of my SSL just told me 
''The SSL that we provide with your contract only protect one domain OR one subdomain, not both''. They told them then that it's why bebechan.net/ebook wasn't protected but bebechan.net was. 
But, bebechan.net/ebook isn't a subdomain right? It's still part of my domain bebechan.net? Or am I totally wrong? A bit lost here.

### Thanks!

I saw similar questions but they didn't resolve my issue.

I have an active SSL on my WordPress website (hosted by IONOS 1and1). If I enter my `example.com` it goes to HTTPS. If I enter `example.com/smth` it goes to HTTP (without s), if I enter `www.example.com/smth` if goes to HTTPS!

So my wish is to force HTTPS on `example.com/smth`. I created a `.htaccess` file through Filezilla entering all the code I could find for example :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

I tried it with the wordpress addition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE] 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But nothing seems to redirect! (The page is `bebechan.net/ebook`). Maybe I've done something wrong creating the `.htacces` or something?

**EDIT:** Actually, I just checked right now and it's written that the SSL is provided for `clickandbuild/bebechan` and I indeed have a `clickandbuild` folder when I check my FTP (see screenshot below) and there is already a `.htaccess` there. Maybe that's the issue? Maybe I should edit this one instead of creating a new one in the root?

[image: FTP - Directory Structure]

So Actually there is already an `.htaccess` in the folder `.../clickandbuild/bebechan` which might be where my SSL is. Looks like there is already a https forced written here. Still not working tho. I'm super lost haha.

Content of the `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/cache-manifest
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vcard
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/vtt
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/x-cross-domain-policy
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/ld+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/manifest+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/schema+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.geo+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-web-app-manifest+json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/eot
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/bmp
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/vnd.microsoft.icon
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/x-component A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/javascript A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/x-js A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/html A3600
    ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
    ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
    ExpiresByType video/asf A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/avi A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/bmp A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/java A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/divx A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/msword A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/gif A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/json A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/midi A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/quicktime A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/mpeg A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/pdf A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/png A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-tar A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/tiff A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/wav A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/wma A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/zip A2419200
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.bebechan.net/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "tried it with the wordpress addition" - You appear to be using "pretty permalinks", so presumably if you first tried it without the WP section your site did not function correctly? "creating the .htacces or something" - To clarify, `.htaccess` should have 2 `s` at the end. WordPress is installed in the document root and you have no other `.htaccess` files? Do both `example.com` and the www subdomain resolve to the same place and serve the same content?

Comment: You may be working on your site currently, but there appears to be multiple redirects going on? HTTP to HTTPS and back to HTTP(?), with and without the www subdomain. How is your SSL cert managed? Is the cert installed directly on your application server? Or are you using some kind of front-end proxy? Have you configured WordPress itself with the correct www / non-www and HTTP / HTTPS preference? Since WP will also try to redirect the request and your `.htaccess` could simply be conflicting with this.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. I'm still working on my website right now even If I already put everything online. I am very beginner at this so I'm not sure I can answer well all of your questions. The SSL was provided by my host IONOS 1&1. Actually, I just checked right now and it's written that the SSL is provided for 'clickandbuild/bebechan' and I indeed have a clickandbuild folder when I check my FTP (like here https://ibb.co/sFjth69) and there is already a .htaccess there. Maybe that's the issue? Maybe I should edit this one instead of creating a new one in the root?

Comment: About wordpress, I'm not sure how is it installed and I havent configured wordpress to do anything. Maybe I should?

Comment: Here is what's written on the .htaccess in the 'clickandbuild/bebechan'

Comment: The ebook folder can be part of a sub domain if you assign it to an alias like myalias.example.com same as www.example.com the www is an alias for your domain that refer to your main directory. But this is not the subject as you can't use your .htaccess file to make http go to https this is because your host is not letting you do that so you can ask them to make the http to https referral by them self’s or you can follow this tutorial on https://websitesetup.org/http-to-https-wordpress/  to have https on your word press

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** You're HTTP to HTTPS redirect is in the wrong place. It needs to go near the start of the `/clickandbuild/bebechan/.htaccess` file, not at the end. (See below for further explanation.)

---

There seems to be a lot of misinformation / confusion here...

> The host that takes care of my SSL just told me "The SSL that we provide with your contract only protect one domain OR one subdomain, not both"

That should OK, you only appear to have one domain. However, your SSL cert does need to cover both the domain apex (ie. `example.com`) and the www subdomain (ie. `www.example.com`) - it should do - I would be very surprised if it didn't. And by what you stated at the start of the question; it does.

> They told them then that it's why `bebechan.net/ebook` wasn't protected but `bebechan.net` was.

That's nonsense. The security certificate (SSL cert) protects hostnames, not subdirectories. If `example.com` is protected then `example.com/ebook` is also protected, as is `example.com/<anything>`.

> But, `bebechan.net/ebook` isn't a subdomain right? It's still part of my domain `bebechan.net`?

Exactly.

> I just checked right now and it's written that the SSL is provided for 'clickandbuild/bebechan' and I indeed have a clickandbuild folder when I check my FTP ... and there is already a `.htaccess` there. Maybe that's the issue? Maybe I should edit this one instead of creating a new one in the root?

It's possible that the *document root* is set to the directory `/clickandbuild/bebechan`, but as noted above, SSL certs cover hostnames, not subdirectories.

For the sake of the rest of this answer, I will assume that `/clickandbuild/bebechan` is actually the document root directory. ie. the directory that is served when you request `http://example.com/` (HTTP and HTTPS).

Your FTP screenshot is confusing/ambiguous. If there is a `.htaccess` file in the `/clickandbuild/bebechan` subdirectory then presumably that is where WordPress is installed? However, your screenshot appears to show a `.htaccess` file and WordPress installation in the *root* directory?! I assume this is *above* the document root? So, what do these files relate to?

> ...there is already a `.htaccess` there. Maybe that's the issue? Maybe I should edit this one instead of creating a new one in the root?

This could very well be the issue. You should not need to manually create the `.htaccess` file. WordPress will create (and use) one by default - it is necessary to drive the WordPress "pretty" permalinks, which you appear to already be using.

So yes, edit the existing `.htaccess` file. Do not create another `.htaccess` file elsewhere.

If you create a `.htaccess` file in a parent directory (eg. in the root directory from your FTP screenshot - which I assume is where you are creating this `.htaccess` file?) with a mod_rewrite redirect (which is what this is) then it will likely be overridden by the mod_rewrite directives in the subdirectories `.htaccess` file and simply be ignored (which appears to be what is happening).

The end of your existing `/clickandbuild/bebechan/.htaccess` file reads...

> ```
> :
>
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteBase /
>     RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>     RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> </IfModule>
>
> AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php
>
> # BEGIN WordPress
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> </IfModule>
>
> # END WordPress
>
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.bebechan.net/$1 [R,L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

The main problem here is that the HTTP to HTTPS redirect is in the wrong place! It should not be at the end of the config file like this. It needs to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file - importantly, it needs to go *before* the WordPress front-controller (ie. the code block in the `# BEGIN WordPress` ... `# END WordPress` comment markers that currently precedes it).

By placing the redirect at the end, as it appears here then it will not do "much". It will redirect `example.com/` (the document root), but not `example.com/smth` - which is the behaviour you stated initially in your question. However, you also stated that `www.example.com/smth` IS redirected - that behaviour cannot be explained by this.

In the above `.htaccess` file, the WordPress front-controller is also unnecessarily repeated - two blocks of code are identical - this is a mistake.

#### Solution

The end of that `.htaccess` file should read like the following instead:

> ```
> :
>
> AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php
>
> # HTTP to HTTPS redirect
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
> RewriteRule (.*) https://www.bebechan.net/$1 [R=301,L]
>
> # BEGIN WordPress
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> </IfModule>
>
> # END WordPress
> ```

---

> About wordpress, I'm not sure how is it installed and I havent configured wordpress to do anything. Maybe I should?

Yes, you should. Either using a plugin or manually... you need to ensure that the "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" are set correctly (ie. probably to `https://www.example.com/`). You may need to also set `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` in the `wp-config.php` file. There is more information about configuring WordPress elsewhere.

You don't want your `.htaccess` redirects to conflict with what WordPress thinks your canonical URL should be.

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much to take the time to explain clearly everything, It was really useful. It's still not working sadly. I did an update/edit on my post to let you know what I did.

Comment: Not sure what I did right, but it's working now and this answer is the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following code will redirect all to `https://www....`. Make sure you are not using any other Wordpress plugin or configuration that could generate a conflict with it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sadly, It is not working: (. I guess I'm doing something wrong. I put this code in an .htaccess file through FTP. Any idea what config could generate a conflict with it?

Comment: This is really no different to the code the OP already presented in their first example. If the OP's code didn't work, then this isn't going to work either.

Comment: Hi there, as the OP said "entering all the code I could find for example... or ..." I just wanted to provide a functional code, just to make sure he is using a working one. Now we can determine that the problem might be a configuration conflict.

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering :). What could be the next step?

Answer (score 0):

You must activate the option **AllowOverride All** to use *.htaccess* file. Also, you can add the Rewrite rules inside the Directory in the conf file like the below example or on your .htaccess file.

```
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs">
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com  [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com 
RewriteRule ^https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have changed my Directory in Conf file to only:

```
 <Directory "/srv/www/htdocs">
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

And inserted in *.htaccess* the following only:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

So If this don't work contact your host to add **AllowOverride All** only.

Comment: `AllowOverride` must already be set correctly as they appear to be using WordPress permalinks.

Comment: Add the Rewrite rules only on your htaccess file. The directory part should been set by your host. So test the Rewrite rules if it don't work contact your host to add AllowOverride All to your directories on the http server conf

Comment: @TalalAl-Khalifa I simply exemplified the domain name (according to [RFC2606](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606)) and retained the original intent of your code example. Using your own personal domain name in your code example and linking back to your personal website to supposedly "demonstrate" that _your arbitrary code snippet_ works on _your server_ is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @MrWhite RFC2060 talks about RDNS, what has it to do with this! Demonstration is part of learning, I made it to show that it works, nothing more. And if you see it irrelevant! I don't. I have undone what you did and removed my domain and added example instead and inserted my example domain to the comments.